# Socket.io connection not working in Flutter and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io

please I am using the socket_io_client package in Flutter to work with socket io in Nodejs. The socket.io is running fine on the server (Nodejs) but on the client (Flutter) it can't connect to the server. Here is my code below:

Server code

```
const express = require( 'express' ),
    app = express(),
    httpServer = require( 'http' ).createServer( app ),
    io = require( 'socket.io' )( httpServer );
httpServer.listen( 3000, () => console.log( 'Server is running' ) );
let connectedUsers = [];
io.on( 'connection', ( socket ) =>
{
    console.log(socket.id);
    connectedUsers.push( {
        socketId: socket.id,
    } );

    socket.on( 'connectedUsers', ( _ ) =>
    {
        socket.broadcast.emit( 'connectedUsers', connectedUsers );
    } );

    socket.on( "connectedUser", ( data ) =>
    {
        console.log( data );
        const { userId, userName } = data;
    });

    socket.on( 'disconnect', () =>
    {
        const disConnectedUsers = connectedUsers.filter(
            ( user ) => user.socketId !== socket.id
        );
        const leavingUser = connectedUsers.find(
            ( user ) => user.socketId === socket.id
        );
        connectedUsers = disConnectedUsers;
        console.log( connectedUsers );
        connectedUsers.forEach( ( user ) =>
            io.to( user.socketId ).emit( 'leavingUser', leavingUser )
        );
    } );
} );
```

Client code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:line_icons/line_icons.dart';
import 'package:sharpcall/providers/theme_notifier.dart';
import 'package:sharpcall/views/components/destination_item.dart';
import 'package:sharpcall/views/screens/contact_screen.dart';
import 'package:sharpcall/views/screens/phone_screen.dart';
import 'package:sharpcall/views/screens/favorite_screen.dart';
import 'package:sharpcall/views/screens/setting_screen.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as client;

final _stateBottomIndex = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final StateNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier, bool> themeNotifier;

  const MainScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.themeNotifier,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final PageController _pageController =
      PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true);

  @override
  void initState() {
    client.Socket socket = client.io('http://192.168.42.51:3000');
    socket.onConnect((data) => socket.emit("connectedUser", {
          "userId": socket.id,
          "userName": "Woo Bear",
        }));

    socket.on("connectedUsers", (data) => print(data));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, child) {
        final stateBottomIndex = watch(_stateBottomIndex);
        return Scaffold(
          body: SizedBox(
            child: PageView(
              allowImplicitScrolling: true,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                stateBottomIndex.state = value;
              },
              children: [
                const PhoneScreen(),
                const ContactScreen(),
                const FavoriteScreen(),
                SettingScreen(
                  themeNotifier: widget.themeNotifier,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarTheme(
            data: NavigationBarThemeData(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
              indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: NavigationBar(
              selectedIndex: stateBottomIndex.state,
              onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                _pageController.animateToPage(
                  value,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                );
                stateBottomIndex.state = value;
              },
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              destinations: [
                DestinationItem(
                  stateBottomIndex: stateBottomIndex.state,
                  icon: LineIcons.phone,
                  name: "Phone",
                  initialIndex: 0,
                ),
                DestinationItem(
                  stateBottomIndex: stateBottomIndex.state,
                  icon: Icons.perm_contact_calendar_outlined,
                  name: "Contacts",
                  initialIndex: 1,
                ),
                DestinationItem(
                  stateBottomIndex: stateBottomIndex.state,
                  icon: LineIcons.star,
                  name: "Favorites",
                  initialIndex: 2,
                ),
                DestinationItem(
                  stateBottomIndex: stateBottomIndex.state,
                  icon: LineIcons.cogs,
                  name: "Settings",
                  initialIndex: 3,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: stateBottomIndex.state == 2
              ? FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.star_border,
                    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color,
                  ),
                )
              : null,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am using my remote IP address to test the app on my real Android device. Please did I miss something or need configuration on the server? Help me out please.

Comment: You said it's running fine on the server, how did you test this? Can you connect with other clients?

Comment: Yes, it is running fine on the server but the client can't connect to the server. I thought it didn't work because of the IP address, no?

Comment: I am testing the app on a real Android device that's why I used the IP address.

Comment: How do you know if the server is running fine, if you could not connect to it? Again my question: did you connect *in any other way* to the server, so your sentence "it's running fine on the server" is backed by an empirical test and not only faith?

Comment: Okay. I run the server - nodejs and the client (browser) did connect to the server locally. Then I used the socket_io_client package to connect to the server but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a local server you'll need a reverse proxy to connect to your server. If your android device is connected via USB try running `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000` in your terminal and you'll be able to connect to your local nodejs server

Comment: Okay. Tried but still not connected. 

Comment: The issue got fixed by downgrading Socket.io version to 2.4.1 for Nodejs. It worked on both real Android device and emulator. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah it was my problem back in the day , i t ried. Glad you solved it!

Comment: @LeslieJoe, please i need your help, am having the same issue too, what was the version of your socket_io_client?

Comment: @Zionnite, you can use the latest socket_io_client.